# Using PDO to replace mysql_connect - formatting correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, echo

This is my current page:

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mypass') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('radio1') or die (mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, TIME_FORMAT(airtime, '%H:%i') `airtime` 
from presenters");
//Table starting tag and header cells
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    <?php foreach($rows as $row):?>
        <dl class="standard">
            <dt><a href="<?=$row=['link'] ?>" title="<?=$row=['presenter'] ?>"><?=$row['airtime'] . " - " .$row['presenter']?></a></dt>
            <dd class="itemimg"><a href="<?=$row=['link'] ?>" title="<?=$row=['presenter'] ?>"><img src="<?=$row['image']; ?>" width="100" height="75" alt="<?=$row=['presenter'] ?>" title="<?=$row=['presenter'] ?>" /></a></dd>
            <dd class="itemdesc">
                <?=$row['showinfo']; ?>
            </dd>
            <dd class="itemlink">
               <a href="<?=$row=['link'] ?>" title="Find out more..."><span> </span>
                        <?=$row['more']; ?></a>

            </dd>
        </dl>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

I want to convert this to code that works with PDO, since it is enabled in my php.ini

How would I get PDO to work with this, as I'm intending on (for this project and all future ones) phasing out use of the older mysql_connect.

I had a look at how to do it at the [Zend Developer Zone](https://devzone.zend.com/1746/building-template-driven-web-applications-with-dwoo-part-1/) and although I can do it at an average level for Dwoo-based projects, this template **does not** use a templating engine - it is pure PHP-based syntax, no templates used, only various `include()` and require, plus `echo()` where needed.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please show what you tried. It is boring just write it for you.

Comment: @xdazz - The code is at http://pastebin.com/atJF6TcZ

Comment: You should really read the manual about pdo. That's how I learned, and out took me exactly ten minutes to master the basics. It also has good examples on how to use it correctly. +1 for converting from mysql to pdo. [Manual Entry on PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I have had a look; will read more in-depth. However, if pdo isn't enabled on a webhost [not all will]; do I just need to create a php.ini or .htaccess to enable it for my site? As for echoing the data within the dl/dd, is that possible without doing what's in my above code?

Comment: @radiogeek86 What error did you have?

Comment: I haven't yet tried doing $row['variable'] as echo with the PDO code yet, so can't really say.

Comment: well, you should try. the code at pastebin looks like it's working

Answer (score 5):

Here is your solution.

```
<?php

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "mypass";
$dbname = 'radio1';
$dbh =null;
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
   echo $e->getMessage();
}

$result = $dbh->query("SELECT *, TIME_FORMAT(airtime, '%H:%i') `airtime` from presenters");
//Table starting tag and header cells
while($row = $result->fetch ()) {
?>
<?php foreach($rows as $row):?>

    <dl class="standard">
     <dt><a href="<?=$row=['link'] ?>" title="<?=$row=['presenter'] ?>"><?=$row['airtime'] . " - " .$row['presenter']?></a></dt>
        <dd class="itemimg"><a href="<?=$row=['link'] ?>" title="<?=$row=['presenter'] ?>"><img src="<?=$row['image']; ?>" width="100" height="75" alt="<?=$row=['presenter'] ?>" title="<?=$row=['presenter'] ?>" /></a></dd>
            <dd class="itemdesc">
                  <?=$row['showinfo']; ?>
                </dd>
                <dd class="itemlink">
           <a href="<?=$row=['link'] ?>" title="Find out more..."><span>
</span>
    <?=$row['more']; ?></a>

                    </dd>
</dl>
<?php endforeach;?>
```