# PHP echo and PDO - how to resolve member function query error?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, echo

This is a continuation of my previous question at [Using PDO to replace mysql_connect - formatting correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207427/using-pdo-to-replace-mysql-connect-help-with-formatting-correctly)

*This is part of a larger page which itself will be echo'd into another page*

```
<?php
/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'root';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'MYPASSWORD';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=radiotest", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/

    /*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM presenters";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {
        }

    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
<?php foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) ?>
<table>
<td>
<tr><?php echo $row['presenter'] ?><?php echo $row['show'] ?>  </tr>
</table>
```

It gave this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\www\vhosts\localhost\radio1.php on line 29
```

I want to avoid this error, and be able to echo the rows if I can... without using this code (my original coding - it worked, but I'm trying to use PDO with echo like in the example above):

```
    <?php
/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'root';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'MYPASSWORD';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=radiotest", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/

    /*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM presenters";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {
        echo $row['presenter'] .' - '. $row['show'] . '<br />';
        }

    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

What could be causing this error, and why?

What should I do with the code to ensure that this is looped:

```
<table>
<td>
<tr><?php echo $row['presenter'] ?><?php echo $row['show'] ?>  </tr>
</table>
```

Basically, I'm trying to use PDO to replace the mysql_connect for echoing rows in tables or definition lists in HTML for my testing site.

Here's the edited version now:

```
<?php
/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'root';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'MYPASSWORD';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=radiotest", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/

    /*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM presenters";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {
                echo $row['presenter'] .' - '. $row['show'] . '<br />';

        }

    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>

<table>
<td>
<tr><?php echo $row['presenter'] ?><?php echo $row['show'] ?> </tr>
</table>
```

It displays the data, but not within the table below.

Comment: 1) Either create your table content before you close the connection in your try block. || 2) Close the connection at the bottom of the page with `$dbh=null`.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `$dbh = null;`. So `$dbh` is not available anymore at line 29.

Furthermore it's pretty inefficient what you are doing in your first example. You are querying the database twice. Better save the result set first time around, and use that later on, if necessary.

You probably need something like the following:

```
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=radiotest", $username, $password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM presenters";
    $result = $dbh->query( $sql );

    // not really necessary
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>

<?php
    // using alternative foreach syntax 
    foreach($result as $row):
?>
<table>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['presenter']; ?><?php echo $row['show']; ?>  </td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
    // using alternative syntax 
    endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: OK, do I just edit it to $dbh ? As for the echo part, what do I do to ensure it loops (it's foreach, isn't it, or am I wrong?)

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question, and elaborate on what you are trying to achieve. That will probably save us commenting back and forth. ;-) Thanks.

Comment: @radiogeek86: I've edited my question. This should do pretty much what you want. Mind you that you can only iterate through `$result` once. If you need it again, then save the `$result` rows in an array first (by iterating through $result as well), in the `try` block. And iterate through the saved array later on.

Answer (score 1):

You're killing your database handle at the bottom of the `try` block. You open a connection, run a query, fetch the results, throw away the results, then close the connection.

So by the time PHP reaches line 29, $dbh is now NULL and can't be used as a PDO object anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You define `$dbh` inside of a try block. Out doesn't exists outside of out, yet you are trying to use it. Get rid of the try block. If an exception will be thrown, the script will automatically stop.

Also, you're setting it to `null` at the end of your deceleration.

Also why are you trying to access dbh outside of the try block? I see no purpose.

Comment: If you look at the documentation of PDO, if you do not put a try catch it will display a backtrace which can possibly expose all of your db info.

Comment: True but it saves no purpose in the development stage. Only on production sites.

Comment: `$dbh` *will* be available in the global scope of the script after the `try` block, if he removes `$dbh = null;`.

Comment: @afuzzyllama - the edited code is above for all to comment on.

Comment: It won't unless he defines it outside the block **and** uses `global` before he edits it.

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin - which part do I define?

Comment: $dbh should be defined outside the try block, and you should call `global $dbh` inside the try block before you edit it.

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin; feel free to take my code and post an improved version on Pastebin if you wish; I'll try it and see if it works!

Comment: I'm afraid I'm on mobile ATM. So not really possible. Tomorrow if no one had answered yet I'll add it for you.

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin: it *will* be available, try it. You are confusing function/object scope with control structure scope.

Comment: I have already tried it. In fact I,opened a question on the subject. A variable won't exist outside a try block. Just like a function.

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin: What version are you using? Using `PHP 5.2.6` here, and it works fine with me. As I expected. Are you sure you haven't forgotten to remove `$dbh = null;` from OP's example?

Answer (score 0):

PDO is no better than mysql ext
you need more intelligent abstraction layer.

also, echo has nothing to do with PDO. you have to use templates, and divide all your codes into getting data part and displaying data part